# Problem with Pgrouting 1.5

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, linux, vertices

I have PostGIS 2.0.1 and PgRouting latest version. I'm using osm2pgrouting to import OpenStreetMap data everything goes OK the trouble is that I always get source and target columns without data and when I run `SELECT assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');` by hand on PGSQL I get the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "vertices_tmp" LINE 1: SELECT
>   ST_addGeometryColumn(''vertices_tmp'', ''the_geom'', ...
>                                         ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "vertices_tmp" SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 31

After hours of reading on the net I've realized that the function assign_vertex_id() had to change somehow because it references other functions like StartPoint that it's called ST_StartPoint and I've changed that but I still get errors.

Where can I get the .sql file with the proper SQL to make the upgrade and postgis/pgrouting can work together?

Answer (score 1):

The `assign_vertex_id` function of pgRouting, that is used to build the road network topology, doesn't work with PostGIS 2.0 (yet), because it still makes use of a few PostGIS functions without "ST_" prefix.
Here is an updated function that should work: https://github.com/mbasa/pgrouting/blob/master/core/sql/routing_topology.sql

Also it's not possible anymore to have a geometry type `MULTILINESTRING`, so osm2pgrouting requires the following fix: https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting/commit/2a20f6e9b1c7ae34e7f60246aa4c7679cfe59e80

Comment: Thanks Dkastl, i'll give it a try and post the results. thank you again for your answer and time.